# How TaskTrackers informs Jobtrackers about their state?

Tags: networking, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I read about the Apache Hadoop. They said that in HDFS, tasks are any process, that is, mapper  or reducer. And they together called jobs.

They have two things, **JOBTRACKER, and TASKTRACKER** , tasktracker is on each node that manages mapper or reducer tasks.

And, Jobtracker is the one, who manges all task-trackers.

Till now I understand all the concpts theoretically, and all the things are well explained in many blogs.

But I have one doubt, how tasktracker inform jobtracker that given task fail. How they communicate each other. Is they using any other software just like , Apache AVRO.

Please explain me the internal mechanism of this.

Looking for your kind reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVRO has nothing to do with this. It is just a serialization framework, which folks usually use if they feel that Hadoop's serialization is not helping them much. Otherwise it is just another member of the Hadoop ecosystem.

Coming to your original question, it is done through heartbeats, as @thiru_k has specified above. But along with the number of available slots heartbeat signals contains some other info as well, like  job status, resource usage, etc. Tasks which don't report their progress for a while are marked as hung or killed. I would suggest you to go through this [link](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/), it'll answer all your questions.

Comment: Actually I am working on a project. In that project they using Avro, Hadoop, Lucene, Solr. I understand all these products except Avroin my project. Can you please elaborate this. Why Avro used? What they do ? and all such questions, or give any useful.

Answer (score 1):

The TaskTrackers sends out heartbeat messages to the JobTracker, usually every few minutes, to reassure the JobTracker that it is still alive. These message also inform the JobTracker of the number of available slots, so the JobTracker can stay up to date with where in the cluster work can be delegated